# Div automatically converts into <p> tag in the Trumbowyg editor

Tags: trumbowyg

Consider:

[image]

I'm using the [Trumbowyg](https://alex-d.github.io/Trumbowyg/documentation/) HTML editor. In this editor, I've entered some HTML content in the code section, but after adding the HTML, the `<div>` tags are automatically converted into `<p>` tags.

How can I prevent/disable this behavior?

Comment: Did you checking the editor's configuration settings? You may need to modify the editor's configuration settings

Comment: Please check this https://github.com/Alex-D/Trumbowyg/issues/990

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried using [Text Editor](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/gedit) and had the same problem; I attempted to fix it by using the following code:

```
Trumbowyg.prototype = { DEFAULT_SEMANTIC_MAP: { 'b': 'strong', 'i': 'em', 's': 'del', 'strike': 'del', 'div': 'p' }}
```

('div': 'p' remove this attribute from above code inside your .js file.)

Try to find this keyword in your JavaScript file: **"DEFAULT_SEMANTIC_MAP"**.

After removing it, the code will look like this:

```
Trumbowyg.prototype = { DEFAULT_SEMANTIC_MAP: { 'b': 'strong', 'i': 'em', 's': 'del', 'strike': 'del'}}
```